# No class def found error even though the jar is added to classpath

Tags: java, cmd, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am running Java program from command line. I am referring to only 1 external jar file. i have added entire path to that jar in classpath. even then i get no class def found error while running program in command line. Program compiles without any error.

Comment: enter you terminal command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including all the jars in a directory within the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath)

Answer (score 1):

I think you complied and run the Java program like this

```
javac -cp fullyqualifiedPathToExternalJar yourfilepath/filename.java
java -cp fullyqualifiedPathToExternalJar yourfilepath/filename
```

> This is totally wrong. When you compiled and run in this manner program compile successfully but not run. This because you have to follow the syntax of java command Properly.

for compiling its Ok.

```
javac -cp fullyqualifiedPathToExternalJar yourfilepath/filename.java
```

To run the program you have to add your file path to the classpath:

```
java -cp fullyqualifiedPathToExternalJar;yourfilepath filename.java //in windows
java -cp fullyqualifiedPathToExternalJar:yourfilepath filename.java //in linux
```

The syntax is

```
javac example.java
java example
```

with folderpath

```
javac /home/admin/example.java
java -cp /home/admin example//only class name
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be the chances of jar's compatibility issue. check yous inter dependent jar versions.